# How to compare DateTime in custom validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm trying to write a custom validation...people enter in a start and end time into a site and I'm trying to write a validation to check that the end comes after the start.  I've tried to convert it to Unix time, but then I get a noMethodError. I would like to pass the symbols for the start time and end time into this method and then compare the two.

```
  def validates_end_is_after_start(*attr_names)

    start_hour = attr_names[0].to_i
    end_hour = attr_names[1].to_i
```

The problem is that this ends up with a noMethodError for symbol. But that symbol points to a DateTime object (I think), how do I access that object? I think that there's something I don't understand about symbols in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `validate` method which would have access to type-casted dates

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :valid_dates

  def valid_dates
    if start_time >= end_time
      self.errors.add :start_time, ' has to be after end time'
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: slight typo: `' has to be before end time'`

Answer (score 0):

Think of symbols just like strings, but with a lot less of functionality and behavior as objects. You should change your code to following:

```
def validates_end_is_after_start(*attr_names)
  start_hour = self.send(attr_names[0].to_sym).to_i
  end_hour = self.send(attr_names[1].to_sym).to_i
  # ... more code here
end
```

You should also checkout the awesome gem [validates_timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness), which is made to handle validation of date, time and datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ruby on Rails 7.0 there is no need anymore for a custom validation in this case because Rails 7.0 supports [`validates_comparison_of`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#comparison)  like this

```
validates :start_time, comparison: { less_than: :end_date }
```